# Given a range $[a,b] \subset \mathbb R$ and we have to choose a Real number from this range

Tags: probability

Is it possible to find the probability that the number would be less than ((a+b)/2) and greater than (a+b)/5

Comment: Clearly this depends on the choice of distribution.  This was the same problem with [your prior question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2850553/given-a-range-0-n-and-we-have-to-choose-a-real-number-from-this-range#2850553)

Comment: Can you add your own workings on this?  Where did you get stuck, during the process?

Comment: @scentofthetrees: $(a+b)/5$ may be $<a$

Comment: For the uniform distribution, the probability would be the length of the interval $[\max(a,(a+b)/5), (a+b)/2]$ divided by the length of the interval $[a,b]$. So, $[(a+b)/2-\max(a,(a+b)/5)]/(b-a)$.

Comment: @gammatester It may also be $>b$.

Answer (score 0):

**Comment** (with hints): As @lulu has commented, you need to specify a particular distribution.
Often, in elementary courses, when one speaks of picking a real number $X$ from
 $[a,b],$ it is understood that the distribution is $\mathsf{Unif}(a,b),$
which has density function $f_X(x) = \frac{1}{b-a},$ for $a \le x \le b$ and 
$f_X(x) = 0,$ for all other values of $x$.
I hope you can figure out how to solve the problem for a uniform distribution with general parameter values
$a < b,$ and I will leave that to you. (Some of the other Comments should be helpful as you do that.)

For an example, suppose $a = 5$ and $b = 20.$ Then you seek $P(5 \le X \le 12.5) = 7.5/15 = 0.5.$ [Other choices of $a$ and $b$ may not be so tidy; perhaps try $a = -1$ and $b = 1.$]

For $a = 5,\, b=20,$ the figure below shows the density 'curve' (here, part of a 'rectangle') of the random variable $X.$ The
probability $P(5 \le X \le 12.5)$ corresponds to the area beneath the density
and between the vertical dotted lines.

[image]

However, if you choose a different distribution for the random variable $X,$
then you may get a different answer.

*Note:* I hope you will find this site helpful. In order to give you the most helpful answers, we need to see your approach to the problem, and to know
why you are having trouble with it.